# Mongoose connection events with createConnection

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I moved away from using the default connection to a explicitly defined connection.

My code is working except that none of the event handlers which track the state of my mongo connection are firing.

the events used to fire when I was using default mongoose connection. (mongoose.connect).

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    logger = require('../logger'),
    config = require('../config');  

mongoose.connection.on('connecting', function(){
    logger.info("trying to establish a connection to mongo");
});

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
    logger.info("connection established successfully");
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
    logger.error('connection to mongo failed ' + err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function() {
    logger.log('mongo db connection closed');
})

var gracefulExit = function() {
    db.close(function(){
        logger.log("mongoose connection with db " + server + 'is closing');
        process.exit(0);
    });
};

process.on('SIGNT', gracefulExit).on('SIGTERM', gracefulExit);

var db = mongoose.createConnection(config.get('DB_URL'));
module.exports = db;
```

the problem with the code is

1. None of the event handlers are firing.
2. Even the process events on SIGNT and SIGTERM are not firing.

I also tried

```
var db = mongoose.createConnection(config.get('DB_URL'));

db.on('connecting', function(){
    logger.info("trying to establish a connection to mongo");
});
```

but this also doesn't fire.

Comment: Did you try using `mongoose.connect` instead of `mongoose.createConnection`?

Comment: I don't want to use monoose.connect because using a "default" connection seems like a bad practice to me. I would like to use an explicitly defined connection rather than default connection.

Comment: OK, but that's more like standard practice than anything else.

Comment: Your second attempt using `db.on` worked for me with the 'open', 'connected' and 'disconnected' events.

Comment: Ha.. .yes, it was not working for connecting.. but worked for connected. but why is my close method not being called for process exit event?

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I think the reason the close method isn't firing is because 'SIGNT' should be 'SIGINT'

Answer (score 12):

i also faced with this problem,
and finally i solved it, after understood that the `connect()` / `createConnection()` execute before i declare the event handlers.
so the my `open` or `connected` events handlers will never called again.

so by declare them first and just after trying to connect - will solve your problem!

*for example:*

```
try {
  mongoose.connection
    .on('error', err => {
      console.error(err);
    })
    .on('open', err => {
      console.log(`DB connected`);
    })

  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', { useNewUrlParser: true });
} catch (error) {
  handleError(error);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This snippet blow work fine for me

```
const connection = mongoose.createConnection(`mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_URI}`);

connection.on('connected', () => {
  console.log('connected to mongodb');
});

connection.on('disconnected', () => {
  console.log('connection disconnected');
});
```

Comment: Works for me too. Only to mentions the states have changed. There is no more an `error` event. These 5 events are the only available: `disconnected`, `connected`, `connecting`, `disconnecting`, `uninitialized`.

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled over this issue myself and found that I needed to set up the `EventListeners` before the actual connection to the database like so (with async/await):

```js
export class Database {
  public static connect( databaseCredentials: string ) {
    return new Promise( async resolve => {
      // ! The `EventListeners` is setup here.
      mongoose.connection.on( "connected", () => {
        logger.info( "Database has connected successfully." );
      });
      mongoose.connection.on( "error", (error) => {
        logger.error( " Obs! There was an unexpected error connecting to the database.", error );
      });

      // ! The acutal connection to the database happens here.
      await mongoose.connect( databaseCredentials, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        keepAlive: true,
        reconnectInterval: 500,
        connectTimeoutMS: 10000,
      });

      resolve();
    });
  }
}
```

This should also work the same way with `mongoose.createConnections`.

This will yield the result (if successful):

```sh
{ message: 'Database has connected successfully.',
  level: 'info',
  timestamp: '2019-10-11T15:17:16.616Z' }
```

I just wanted to chip in and give my solution to the problem at hand and give a full example implementation of the code, as the above answers didn't explain in which order you needed to listen for the events. If you were to put the `mongoose.connection.on()` below the `await.mongoose.connect()`, this would not yield any response from the `EventListeners`.

*Edit: Typos*

Comment: This should be the right answer, creating the events before connection works for me too.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
mongoose.connection.on('open', function() {
    logger.info("database is ready now");
});
```

also temporary remove .close()